# On simple examples of unimodularity

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples

$w=z=x+ 1 =y−1$ provides $wz−xy=w^2−(w−1)(w+ 1) = 1$. Hence if $x,y$ are odd then $w,z$ are even and all four integers are close.

1. Is there elementary example where only $w$ is even and all four integers are close?

A non-example which is elementary is $w=2$ and $x=y=2k+1$ at a $k\in\mathbb N$ and $z=\frac{xy+1}2$ and it is a non-example because $w$ is a constant and so the integers are not close. However it appears there might be infinite number of examples where $w<z<2w$ and $x=y=2k+1$ holds. But there seems no obvious pattern.

2. Is there a conjecture of sorts relating to squares and these unimodular examples?

Any references?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "close". If you want $x,y,z,w$ to be within $O(1)$ of each other, then there will be only finitely many solutions, with the only exception being the one you gave (up to permutation of variables)

Comment: $|x-y|=O(1)$ and $|z|/|w|=O(1)$ perhaps is a reasonable bound.

Comment: In that case you can have solutions coming from solutions to Pell's equations: if $a^2-2b^2=-1$, then $(x,y,z,w)=(a,a,b,2b)$ satisfies $wz-xy=1$.

Comment: Nice answer. and so perhaps worth elaborating in an answer and also how to find the $a,b$ parameters in polynomial time.

Comment: Finding solutions to Pell equations is standard stuff. Also, $36\times25-31\times29=1$, $36\times49-43\times41=1$, $64\times49-57\times55=1$, and so on.

Comment: Nice answer but if you know a link please feel free to post on Pell.

Comment: Every intro Number Theory textbook treats Pell. Or just type *Pell's equation* into the internet and stand back while hundreds of links come flying at you. But my numerical examples have nothing to do with @Wojowu and Pell. $\{w,z\}=\{a^2,(a+1)^2\}$, $\{x,y\}=\{a^2+a+1,a^2+a-1\}$.

Comment: @gerrymyerson.yes I know your examples are direct.